# Dynamic view models

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, viewmodel, cqrs

If I'm about to split my application into read and write sides using CQRS principles how would you handle situation of having a "dynamic" read model scenario? E.g. I have a product that consists of several read properties (id, title, slug etc) but in order to display it to user I need to pass its price that is calculated by domain service (to which I pass visitor country and currency)? I can't store this price in database because user is free to change his currency anytime he wants + prices change quite often. So my final product view model should be basically a composite of raw-SQL columns (id, title, slug) and calculated price. Should I use the same view model that I get from the database and use content enrichment pattern or should I create a new view model for my composite?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the price of the product is a COMMAND, it should update the price you store in the database which you then QUERY anytime.

The essence of CQRS is that your queries are not going any logic like that.

For currency conversion, since you say the user can change currency at anytime then you should query the entire list of currency rates and do the calculation yourself on the client side.  Alternatively you could query for the base price then query for the current rate.  And if the user changes currency you just query for the rate again but keep the same base price.